# Query to find Blocks on Moodle courses as per categories

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to put together a query that shows the number of different blocks being used in a particular course category in Moodle (or in different courses in a category).

eg.

Category 1
Block_name  Number_of_instances
HTML        6
Calendar    7

Basically want to know which blocks are being used the most in a course category.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had to supply a particular category id for my use.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT cat.id AS catid, cat.name AS catname, b.blockname, COUNT(*)
FROM mdl_context x
JOIN mdl_block_instances b ON b.parentcontextid = x.id
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = x.instanceid
JOIN mdl_course_categories cat ON cat.id = c.category
WHERE x.contextlevel = 50
GROUP BY cat.id, cat.name, b.blockname
ORDER BY cat.name, 4 DESC, b.blockname
```

Comment: Thank you Russell, for your query. Modified the query a bit to get my desired output. Many thanks again.